# Is supervisord shutting down gracefully?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, supervisord

I have process that needs arbitrary amount of time to shutdown, anywhere between 2 seconds and couple of minutes. It is important that this process exits gracefully (not killed). I use supervisord and ubuntu server to run it.

When the server get ACPI shutdown signal (reboot command from a VPS provider, that's what EC2 does I assume), will supervisord (and the whole system) wait for all the child processes to exit during shutdown sequence?

Comment: My limited experience is that the children don't get `stopsignal` at shutdown. They just get killed the hard way with everything else. Like I said that's just what it looks like is happening. I don't have a machine to truly test this on.

Answer (score 7):

You should check out the following configuration options:

`stopsignal` to specify which signal gets sent to your program in order to tell it to stop gracefully

`stopwaitsecs` to specify how long supervisord should wait for the process to stop gracefully, before giving up and sending a SIGKILL.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings